# Testing installer - browsercam for apps

Tags: .net, testing, executable

I have an installer .net application and want to test on xp - win 7 on 32 and 64 bit machines. does anyone know of a service that you can remote to machines, install stuff and then kill them when you are done?

Its basically browsercam for non web apps.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual machines?

Comment: Ya basically just a bunch of vm's. browser cam will let us install small things but our installer is 250mb and it doesnt like that.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello. You can write script for automation install/uninstall app. 
You can try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). 
I have written script for install application that  was developed by InstallAware.